# Javadoc for a static "overloaded" method

Tags: javadocs, method-overloading

My problem is the following:

I have an interface that requires its implementations to implement a static method, namely `void load()`. However, until Java 8, it seems we won't get static methods in interfaces. I trust my users to still implement it correctly, but my problem is how to write a proper doc.

There are up to 50 implementations of this interface and not being able to inherit the javadoc is a bother.

What is the best way to proceed in my case? Should I document a random implementation and add `@see` annotations in the others? It seems dirty to me.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want to introduce an abstract class that implements the behavior?

Comment: as @MikePartridge implied, [Composition over Inheretance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: @MikePartridge: I'm not sure of what you're proposing. This behavior depends on the classes and I'd like the interface to stay static. I'm certainly missing your point so please extend your suggestion! :)

Comment: My question refers to creating an abstract class that implements your interface which would become a parent of your various implementations. The abstract class could define the load method and house the javadoc for it. As @Ampt suggested however, you could also extract the load logic to a static class which your implementations would delegate to, and your interface would then contain a link to the static class's load method documentation. This would avoid inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated, there isn't a way (until Java 8) for an interface to require a static method.  There also isn't a way to override a static method, so which documentation could actually be inherited?

I see a few options:

- If the documentation on the interface describes the method (which I would expect - how are implementers supposed to know about the `load()` method?), have the docs of all implementations link to it:

  /** required static method as expected by {@link Loadable} */
- If there is a sane default implementation for the `load()` method, put it in an abstract class implementing the interface and have the docs for all implementations link to it (rather than just a random implementation):

  /** @see AbstractLoadable#load() */
- Extract the polymorphic functionality in the `load()` method to a non-static method.  The interface can then explicitly require the new method, and javadoc will automatically inherit the documentation from the interface.  (I realize this might not be a viable option)